# Junit testing started spring context

Tags: spring, junit

I have a junit test case that instantiates and configures a spring context with 
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)

In this spring context I have beans implementing the Lifecycle interface.

How do I "start" the spring context before the tests are invoked and stop it again afterwards?

Answer (score 3):

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "/applicationContext-TEST.xml")
public class MyIntegrationTest {}
```

then just reference beans as you normally would

Answer (score 0):

`@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` over class named `MyTestCase` is enough. [Spring test framework](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/testing.html) will look for `MyTestCase-test.xml` file on the CLASSPATH. If you don't like this naming convention, you can specify your own one:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "/applicationContext.xml")
public class MyTestCase {

  @Autowired
  private Dependency dep;

}
```

> How do I "start" the spring context before the tests are invoked and stop it again afterwards?

Typically you don't have to do anything. Spring will start application context before the first test and shut it down automatically when JVM running the tests closes. Also you can restart context after each test (see `@DirtiesContext` annotation).

Comment: Are you sure? It seems that in my case the application context is not "started". I am referring to "start" in the Lifecycle sense (as defined by the Lifecycle interface).

Comment: @DennisThrysøe The start portion of the Lifecycle will execute (as I rely on it to connect to RabbitMQ for my own tests), but as Tomasz mentioned it should only happen **once** per test suite execution (ie JVM load). One caveat to this is: If your tests fail to load the context Spring will try to reload the context on every test (yes that is very slow). Make sure that your context isn't silently failing (generally though you'll know when it fails).

Comment: I use @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) but the application context is NOT started. If I start it manually before each test, everything works well. Any ideas what will make the created application context *not* start?